# Lista dentro da Section

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho uma `section` de tamanho limitado e tenho algumas opções "radio" dentro dela.
Quero que essas opções não saiam de dentro da section. Quando ficar grande, quero uma barra de rolagem dentro da `section` para visualizar todas as opções.

```js
#racetype{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: D3D3D3;
max-width: 120px;
max-height: 480px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Builder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/racetype.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="racetype">
            <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('aasimartree');racebonus(0)"> Aasimar </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('dragonborntree');racebonus(1)"> Dragonborn </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('drowelftree');racebonus(2)"> Drow </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('dwarftree');racebonus(3)"> Dwarf </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('elftree');racebonus(4)"> Elf, Khorvaire </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('woodelftree');racebonus(5)"> Elf, Wood </p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: E onde está sua lista `<ul>` e `<li>`?

Comment: Desculpe, corrigi o texto lá, é uma relação de "radio"s na verdade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, é so utilizar a propriedade `overflow: auto` que ao chegar no tamanho máximo da section ele cria uma barra de rolagem.

```css
#racetype{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: D3D3D3;
max-width: 120px;
max-height: 480px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Builder</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/racetype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="racetype">
 <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('aasimartree');racebonus(0)"> Aasimar </p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('dragonborntree');racebonus(1)"> Dragonborn </p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('drowelftree');racebonus(2)"> Drow </p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('dwarftree');racebonus(3)"> Dwarf </p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('elftree');racebonus(4)"> Elf, Khorvaire </p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="raceimg('woodelftree');racebonus(5)"> Elf, Wood </p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo!